# Firebase-tool missed sending my Js files as HTML file in locally testing mode

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

Currently I use firebase-hosting and firebase-database to deploy a static-page web app. And I got a problem in test my hosting in local. One of my two Js files, `modules.js` and `main.js`, got send as a html file. So in my client browser (Firefox), all way got this error in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

I tried to change the `headers` item in Firebase config:

```
"headers": [
    {
        "source": "**/*.@(js)",
        "headers": [
            {
                "key": "Content-Type",
                "value": "application/javascript; charset=utf-8"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Even the header is changed, the file is still served with HTML content. (In network tab, it say js, but its response is still html content, not js content.)

And of course, I restarted the local server as well. I also disable cache in dev tool to make sure my browser keep downloading newest file. The only option left is restart the whole computer. But even if it can fix it. I still would like to know why is this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This generally happens when you have a rewrite for a Single-Page App (e.g. `{"source": "**", "destination": "/index.html"}` and your `<script>` tag has an invalid `src` URL, so `index.html` is served instead.

I would check for the following issues:

1. Are you using relative paths (e.g. `js/modules.js`) from a non-root URL?
2. Have you exactly matched the case of the output file?
3. What happens when you try to directly access the JS file by its URL?

Again, the problem is not that the JS file is being served as HTML, it's that your default HTML file is being served when the JS isn't found.

Comment: 1. Yeah, I think I used relative path `<script src='./modules.js'></script>`

Comment: 2. I'm not sure what to match and where to match. Could you please add more detail? Thanks :D

Comment: 3. If I try to directly access it, the browser will display the index.html as plain text. I mean, user will see html code display on the page, just like when you try to read a html.txt on a browser. I have try access to style.css and the other js, main.js, they are both work normal.

Comment: You were right, problem lies in the spelling mistake. Somehow, a tiny comma has magically appeared in the filename even though I used copy/paste. Thanks for your informative support.